# Mongo query in nested fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a DB which has records with nested fields like :

```
"requestParams" : { "query" : [ "tv9" ] }
```

I am using the following query to fetch these kind of records. However I am looking for a more general case wherein the field query matches /tv9/ which includes tv9 as part of any search. Like it should also return livetv9, movietv9, etc. Following query does not seem to work:

```
db.requestLog.findOne({url : /search.json/, requestParams: {$elemMatch: {query: /tv9/}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

$elemMatch is used to match partial document elements inside an array. Since you want to directly match on a string the use of this operator is inappropriate. Use this instead :

```
db.requestLog.findOne({url : /search.json/, 'requestParams.query': /tv9/})
```

Example :

```
mongos> db.test.save({r:{q:["tv9"]}})
mongos> db.test.save({r:{q:["tv"]}})
mongos> db.test.save({r:{q:["ltv9l"]}})
mongos> db.test.find({'r.q':/tv9/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f5095d4ec991a74c16ba862"), "r" : { "q" : [ "tv9" ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f5095deec991a74c16ba864"), "r" : { "q" : [ "ltv9l" ] } }
```

Comment: i tired this, it returns null however when i used the query i posted earlier it returns 16 but i want all strings that have tv9 as substring that means the output should be> 16

Comment: The query I mentioned definitely works if your example is correct. I'll extend my answer with the example.